# How can I get reach demographic details for ad campaigns using Facebook marketing API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm building a system to automatically ingest date from the Facebook API. I can easily get campaign details such as CPC, CPM, Reach, etc. However, now I'd like to grab reach demographic information such as this one below:

[image: Facebook campaign reach demographic]

I believe that it does have something to do with Insights API, however, I can't seem to find any sort of details on the insights docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group/insights/

**UPDATE**

I did see eventually that two possibly useful params in that list are age and gender. In my cloud function I'm already grabbing campaign insights using this:

```
await campaign.getInsights([
    'impressions',
    'cpc',
    'spend',
    'ctr',
    'conversions',
    'clicks',
    'cpm',
    'reach'
]);
```

To which I then added 'age' and 'gender' in the list of fields. However, I then got this error:

```
message: '(#100) age, gender are not valid for fields param. please check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-insights/ for all valid values'
```

This is quite odd, because I was checking their node package you can see that the fields I'm supposed to feed to the getInsights method are fields belonging to the AdsInsights class (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-nodejs-business-sdk/blob/3c0785aba14f44ba52434e66bb80ed410a6ca368/src/objects/campaign.js#L239)

And when I visit the AdsInsights file I can see both 'age' and 'gender' as part of the list of fields: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-nodejs-business-sdk/blob/3c0785aba14f44ba52434e66bb80ed410a6ca368/src/objects/ads-insights.js#L16

Comment: Looks at the `breakdowns` field, there’s `age` and `gender` available there …

Comment: Thanks, I did eventually see them. I updated my question with more findings

Comment: The error message is referring to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-insights/, and that doesn’t list age or gender as valid fields. But I couldn’t tell you whether that is due to your node package doing anything wrong here, or something else. In such a case I’d recommend that you test your requests in Graph API Explorer first, then you can tell whether it is a problem with the parameters, or the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the breakdowns field to params parameter of this function rather than to the fields parameter to this function.
This is taken from Facebook's example (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-nodejs-business-sdk/blob/3c0785aba14f44ba52434e66bb80ed410a6ca368/examples/ads_insights_edge_ad_campaign_insights.js)

```
let fields, params;
fields = [
  'impressions',
];
params = {
  'breakdown' : 'publisher_platform', \\ Replace this with age or gender
};
const insightss = (new AdSet(id)).getInsights(
  fields,
  params
);
logApiCallResult('insightss api call complete.', insightss);
```

Comment: Thanks Idan! That turned out to be the way to go. Unfortunately, however, the response I get from the SDK seems to be truncated. I get the age/gender split just for one age/gender group, whereas if I curl the endpoint using the very same campaign_id, I do get the impressions grouped by age_gender.

I opened an issue on GitHub, if you care to follow -> https://github.com/facebook/facebook-nodejs-business-sdk/issues/127

Comment: The object you are getting should be a generator , try to iterate over the object and print the output

Comment: @ilrock was it the case that it was possible to access it via a generator? Did you ever figure it out?